# Not able to fetch data from mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using express to make serve listen to the request for fetching data from mogno db using mongoose. My index.js for server looks like this.

```
var express = require("express");
var contacts = require("./contact");
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
app.get("/", contacts.index);
app.get('/contacts', contacts.index);
app.listen(1222, "127.0.0.1");
```

My contact.js file structure for fetching data from the database is like following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mukund');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String }
});

var ContactModel = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    return ContactModel.find(function(err, contacts) {
        if (!err) {
            res.jsonp(contacts);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that I have a dumped mongo database and I want to fetch the data from the dumped database. But I don't know about how to fetch the data without my own model. Can anyone suggest me the method of fetching data using mongoose without knowing the model.

A sample row of my data looks like following:

```
    {
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("52cbd53612fd507e06005a6d"),
"activities" : [ ],
"admin" : false,
"created" : ISODate("2014-01-07T10:21:42.753Z"),
"email" : "gopal@mypromovideos.com",
"email_token" : "206140c1-f1f2-4f0c-9956-ea50445dd633",
"email_token_created" : ISODate("2014-01-07T10:21:42.753Z"),
"email_verified" : true,
"geo" : [
    76.98138157922307,
    11.01664471263072
],
"hash" : "$2a$10$.cV3FDS51XnxdiDcM2HJ5uhMANAwTudwDkucse4NToITYDWbkosca",
"last_activity" : ISODate("2014-01-07T10:31:17.508Z"),
"notifications" : [
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("53579f6e3c842fc05200344f"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("53579f6e3c842fc05200344f"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("53579f713c842fc052003462"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-23T11:09:37.892Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("5357e94d3c842fc052003659"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("5357e94d3c842fc052003659"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5357e9573c842fc05200366c"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-23T16:24:55.563Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535912c03c842fc052003863"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535912c03c842fc052003863"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535912c43c842fc052003876"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-24T13:33:56.622Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535913783c842fc052003a70"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535913783c842fc052003a70"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5359137b3c842fc052003a83"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-24T13:36:59.271Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535a9c913c842fc052003c7d"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535a9c913c842fc052003c7d"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535a9c943c842fc052003c90"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:34:12.042Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535a9d693c842fc052003e8c"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535a9d693c842fc052003e8c"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535a9d6b3c842fc052003e9f"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:37:47.302Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535a9e5b3c842fc05200409b"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535a9e5b3c842fc05200409b"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535a9e5e3c842fc0520040ae"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:41:50.092Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535b505e3c842fc0520042aa"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535b505e3c842fc0520042aa"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535b50613c842fc0520042bd"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-26T06:21:21.156Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535bd5013c842fc0520044ba"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535bd5013c842fc0520044ba"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535bd5053c842fc0520044cd"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-26T15:47:17.370Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535c7a023c842fc0520046cb"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535c7a023c842fc0520046cb"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535c7a043c842fc0520046de"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-27T03:31:16.847Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535d08e53c842fc0520048de"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535d08e53c842fc0520048de"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535d08e73c842fc0520048f1"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-27T13:40:55.930Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535dbc0a3c842fc052004af2"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535dbc0a3c842fc052004af2"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535dbc0d3c842fc052004b05"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-28T02:25:17.238Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535de80c3c842fc052004d06"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535de80c3c842fc052004d06"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535de80e3c842fc052004d19"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-28T05:33:02.749Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535e12063c842fc052004f1a"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535e12063c842fc052004f1a"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535e12093c842fc052004f2d"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-28T08:32:09.718Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535e1e313c842fc05200512f"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535e1e313c842fc05200512f"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535e1e333c842fc052005142"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-28T09:24:03.045Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535f11a13c842fc052005344"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535f11a13c842fc052005344"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535f11a43c842fc052005357"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-29T02:42:44.388Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535f13273c842fc052005559"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535f13273c842fc052005559"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535f13293c842fc05200556c"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-29T02:49:13.563Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535f64b83c842fc052005771"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535f64b83c842fc052005771"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535f64bb3c842fc052005784"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-29T08:37:15.953Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("535ff59c3c842fc052005987"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("535ff59c3c842fc052005987"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("535ff59f3c842fc05200599a"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-29T18:55:27.221Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "title" : "shouted",
        "type_id" : ObjectId("5360646c3c842fc052005ba1"),
        "sender" : ObjectId("52a6e799701054a10a000095"),
        "target" : ObjectId("5360646c3c842fc052005ba1"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5360646f3c842fc052005bb4"),
        "private" : false,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-30T02:48:15.011Z")
    }
],
"online" : false,
"password_token" : "4aaf6362-b54a-44ee-a617-caf260675bc3",
"password_token_created" : ISODate("2014-01-07T10:21:42.753Z"),
"profile_image" : "http://lecafe.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/52cbd53612fd507e06005a6d.jpg?v=ebbfcf",
"tokens" : [ ],
"username" : "gopalg"
    }
```

Comment: Well there is a way, and it just basically involves reading the raw collection data from a handle to the underlying node driver. But before writing that up, I'm not too sure what you mean in this context, as if you want to use mongoose then possibly just define a model. Or do you mean you want to read a collection that does not strictly conform to a model you have? Or possibly you are not sure of how to define the model for that data? Whatever the case, you seem to be talking about data that you are not showing here, so possibly show something along the lines of what you actually mean here.

Comment: @NeilLunn yeah i am not sure about how to define the model for that data. I am attaching a simple row of the data in the question inself.